# Will it be possible to use trace statement in for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, trace, comma-operator

I need to print something in each statement of for loop. Because my program is crashing in for loop. So I tried to add trace statement in for loop,

```
for (  ICollection::const_iterator iter = pCol->begin(NULL),OutputDebugString(L"One"); iter != pCol->end(NULL); ++iter)
        { //see OutputDebugString
```

I am getting following error,

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'IIteratable::ConstIterator::ConstIterator(std::auto_ptr<_Ty>)'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [4]' to
>   'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>'  filename.cpp    629

Now I tried same thing in sample application, and it is working fine,

```
void justPrint(std::string s)
{
    cout<<"Just print";
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0,justPrint("a"); i<3; i++)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Both OutputDebugString and justPrint returns void, what wrong I am doing in my code.

Comment: What is the type of `pCol`? Also why using `NULL` in `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: `std::auto_ptr`... some legacy code needs upgrade...

Comment: pCol is smart pointer of some internal type, `TNSmartPtr<IEbCollection> pCol` and NULL is passed, because it takes some session object. All related to internal management. Should it case any kind of error? Because without trace statement everything is fine.

Comment: @BryanChen True. But its huge old legacy code. I am fixing bug on little module. Need lot of re-factoring if try to do so.

Comment: What's the point of including a print statement in the first parameter of the for loop? Since it's only going to be executed once anyway, you'd might as well move it outside of the loop for clarity's sake.

Comment: @MrEricSir I started with first statement only, after that I am adding to remaining both the parts.

Comment: Since you're using MSVC: Use [Trace points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.90).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you are assigning the return value of `OutputDebugString` to `iter`. Try swap the order because comma operator (`,`) gives the last value, which is this case, is the returned value of `OutputDebugString`.

```
for (  ICollection::const_iterator iter = (OutputDebugString(L"One"), pCol->begin(NULL)); iter != pCol->end(NULL); ++iter)
    { //see OutputDebugString
```

But it why you need `OutputDebugString` there? You can just add it before the for loop to avoid the confusion.

---

If you need to print debug string after `pCol->end(NULL)`, you can use a helper function.

```
static ICollection::const_iterator begin_helper(SomeType &pCol) {
    auto iter = pCol->begin(NULL);
    OutputDebugString(L"One")
    return iter;
}

for (  ICollection::const_iterator iter = begin_helper(pCol); iter != pCol->end(NULL); ++iter)
    { //see OutputDebugString
```

Comment: I want to see what happens after assignment and other parts of for loop, because I am getting error in for loop. I mean not in statements of loop, but in definition of loop itself.

Comment: My error is resolved. Thanks. One question, why compiler don't think I am assigning justPrint to i here, `for(i = 0,justPrint("a"); i<3; i++)`

Comment: @PranitKothari Assignment has higher precedence than the comma operator, so that's equivalent to `((i = 0), justPrint("a"))`. `int i = 0, justPrint("a")` fails because it's an initialisation; it's equivalent to `int i = (0,justPrint("a"))`